# JavaScript function to multiply two numbers until they equal each other

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build this function to pass two numbers by the user, and finding the lowest common multiple of the two numbers. I was trying to build the function by using this logic. Keep on multiplying until the result of the two numbers equal each other. I need some help on the logic. Thank you.

```
function performCalc(one, two) {
        var num1 = new Number;
        var num2 = new Number;
        var i = new Number(0);

        var num1 = one;
        var num2 = two;

        var result1 = new Number;
        var result2 = new Number;

        do {
            result1 = num1 * i;
            result2 = num2 * i;
            i++
        }
        while (result1 != result2);
        if (result1 == result2) {
            return result1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be possible that your function does _not_ return anything.

Comment: I think you need to test result1 over result2 on the do loop and then break it and return the data

Comment: For input numbers `x` and `y`, your function computes every possible `x*k` and `y*k` for all values of `k`. However `x*k == y*k` is only true if `x == y` for all values of `k` (you can see that trivially by dividing the equation by `k`). If you want the lowest common denominator need to check that `x / k` is a round number, or -- in JS -- `floor(num1/ i) = (num1 / i)` or, faster, `(num1 % i) == 0`.

Comment: How do you expect the results to ever be the same if you multiply them by the same number?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you want LCM not lowest common denominator. Nirks answer below should cover that.

Answer (score 4):

This will always return 0 because `i` starts at `0`, so `result1` will be 0 and `result2` will be 0.

To find the LCM, you need to test different sets of products (for example, in the case of `LCM(12, 18)`, you need to multiply `18` by `2` and `12` by `3`).

One way to do it is:

```
var i,j;
for(i=1;i <= two; ++i) {
    for(j=1; j<=one; ++j) {
        if(one * i == two * j) { 
            return one * i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @luiges90 there are far more efficient ways to calculate the LCM, like calculating the GCD using the euclid method and then computing one * two / GCD(one, two), but OP wants an incremental method

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that, while `result1` and `result2` may at different times hold equivalent values, they will only ever share the same value at the same time *if* your original inputs `one` and `two` are identical. Because your return conditional relies on the equivalence of these two values, you end up with a function that only returns when `one==two`. An example of your loop with the inputs `3` and `5` would be

1. i = 0, result1 = 0, result2 = 0
2. i = 1, result1 = 3, result2 = 5
3. i = 2, result1 = 6, result2 = 10

... ad infinitum, where `result1` never equals `result2`.

A better solution would take a value `a` (where `a` is the argument with the lowest absolute value) and repeatedly add the number to itself until the total sum `ret` is perfectly divisible by both `a` and `b`. We can make use of the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to check for this condition. This approach also allows us to calculate the 'negative lowest common multiple', if necessary:

```
function lowest_common_multiple(a,b) {
    var max = Math.max(a,b),
        min = Math.min(a,b);
    if(Math.abs(max + min) <= Math.abs(max)) { 
        return 0;
    }
    var abs_min = (Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) ? a : b;
    var ret = abs_min;
    while(1) {
        ret += abs_min; 
        if(!(ret % a || ret % b)) {
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

console.log(lowest_common_multiple(11,27));   // >> +297
console.log(lowest_common_multiple(-11,-27)); // >> -297
```

Note that this implementation return zero if the user passes in a zero for either (or both) arguments, or if one argument is positive while the other is negative.

Answer (score -2):

maybe this will do the trick:

```
do {
  result1 = num1 * i;
  result2 = num2 * i;

  if( result1 == result2 ){ break; }
  i++
}

return result1;
```

as it seems, your code is on an infinite loop, maybe even limit the iterations with something like

```
i++;
if( i > 1000 ){  result1=0; break; } //if it tried 1000 times and found nothing, abort and return zero...
```

Comment: Also, the new Number is flawed as far as i know, why not just initialize with a simple Zero like var i=0, result1=0, result2=0;

Comment: I have no idea why he needs this function, maybe for some homework... and indeed, value1 and value2 will never be equal since they're being multiplied by the same number (i) but i'm just adding my two cents with the seemingly infinite do loop.  Cheers.

Comment: Questioner is asking for an algorithm of getting LCM of two numbers.